# Optimizing MongoDB Indexing

Tags: mongodb, indexing, query-optimization

I am querying a collection where for two array fields I have specific values and for two other fields I only want `{ $exists : true }`.

i.e.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: {array: {$elemMatch: {field1: 'value1', field2: 'value2', field3:{$exists : true}, field4: {$exists : true}}}] },
  {$unwind:array},
  {$project...}
])
```

I have created three indexes:

- index 1: `field1:1, field2:1`
- index 2: `field1:1, field2:1, field3:1`
- index 3: `field1:1, field2:1, field3:1, field4:1`

when I try the explain() method on the query the winning plan always picks up index 1.

Can i create a compound index where all four fields are included to speed up my query? (I have tried partial indexing on fields 3 and 4 but it made no difference)

Comment: Which MongoDB version are you using? I just ran some tests using some 3.6 version and that seems to behave the way you would want it to...

Comment: Using Mongo 3.4. When you say the way I want it, do you mean it's using Index 4?

Comment: Try the latest version of MongoDB perhaps. I created an index covering three fields inside a document that was inside an array and my query had an $exists filter. The index did get used as per the explain() output.

Comment: Delete index1 and index2 because index3 is sufficient in your case. Index3 will be used for all queries which could use (also) index1 or index2.